# Git hotfix branch merge

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, hotfix

What are the best practices of merging `hotfix` branch into `master`/`develop`?

Do I need to merge it into both branches

```
hotfix → master
hotfix → develop
```

or merge to `master` and then to `develop` after.

```
hotfix → master → develop
```

Comment: It depends on how you use develop and master.

Comment: @taskinoor I use them according to [successful git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your hotfix branch into both `master` and `develop` (according the the popular [successful git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/))

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff hotfix

git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff hotfix
```

You can then delete your hotfix branch safely.

Or use `git cherry-pick <hotfix-commit-hash>` on both `develop` and `master` branch.
[Cherry-picking](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) is the easiest way to bring a single/few commit(s) into branches.

Comment: Agree, do you have any remarks about `hotfix → master → develop`

Comment: I'm hoping you meant to say "cherry-picking is the *WORST* way".  It's not a good strategy for that model.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question. I think that the two merging strategies technically have the same results.